# Override ClassNames function without Creating new class that extends ClassName

Tags: java, android, class, overriding

So basically I'm using MyLocationOverlay to draw the users location on the map.  However, I do not like how it is drawn.  I want to have my own icon and remove the circle around the location.

The only way I know how to do this would be to create a new class that extends MyLocationOverlay and then @Override the draw() function (or whatever it is called).

So, is there anyway to do this without making the new class (and "all" of the boilerplate that is needed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is there anyway to do this without making the new class (and "all" of the boilerplate that is needed)?

Short of modifying the Android source code, no.

Comment: maybe I was unclear but my solution is valid, no? (I haven't tried it out yet but my workmate finally got back to me and gave me that answer)

Comment: The answer you posted looks like exactly what you describe in the question, but want to avoid because of "all the boilerplate." Now, I wouldn't consider that to be much boilerplate code, and that _is_ how you override a method, so... I don't know what you want.

Comment: critical lapse of thinking on my part >.< Deletion would be wonderful heh

Answer (score -1):

I found out how >.<

```
ClassName blah = new ClassName() {
    @Override
    function() {}
};
```